# Como pegar vários dados de uma página e exibir separadamente com AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cookies

Tenho um programa em que ele cria cookies com os dados que o usuário digitou nos campos `<input>`. Isso tudo através de AJAX. Até aqui sem problemas, mas nesse arquivo em que faço a requisição, ele me retorna os dados dos cookies criados. O que eu quero é pegar esses dados e colocar em dois outros campos `<input>`.

Um exemplo para esclarecer melhor:

- Dois campos `<input>` nome e email;
- Mando esses dados para outro arquivo que cria os cookies com esses dados;
- E outros dois campos que quero auto-preencher com esse cookies retornados;

Só que quando retornados, eles vem juntos, existe algum `array` para pegar essas informações uma de cada vez?

Um detalhe, utilizo JavaScript puro, nada de jQuery.

Comment: Com que padrão você junta, por exemplo, o nome com o e-mail? Por exemplo: `v_nome + ";" + v_email`.

Comment: Desculpe mas não entendi sua pergunta

Comment: Você disse que os valores dos campos, no seu exemplo teórico, são salvos em um cookie, porém "quando retornados, eles vem juntos". De que maneira você salvou eles juntos? Em outras palavras, como você serializou os dados?

Comment: Eu simplesmente imprimo o cookie na tela antes de retornar. Ex.: echo $_COOKIE['nome']; echo $_COOKIE['email'];

Comment: Ah, entendi, os dados vão parar em cookies particulares :)
Mas se você já separou o joio do trigo, qual o problema?

Comment: Sim, mas quando utilizo a função responseText, ele me retorna esse dois valores com uma única string, por isso queira saber como mandar primeiro o echo $_COOKIE['nome'];  e depois o echo $_COOKIE['email'];

Comment: @Math, em vez de colocar esse tipo de detalhes nos comentários, é melhor [edit] a pergunta para incluí-los.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das soluções, e a que eu considero mais confiável (em termos de possíveis entradas que podem gerar confusão na lógica do script), é pré-formatar a resposta ainda no lado servidor, para que o lado cliente não necessite decodificá-la.

Se você conseguir fazer com que o PHP responda ao Ajax com algo assim:

```
'<script>
    var resposta = {
        "nome": "' . $_COOKIE['nome'] . '",
        "email": "' . $_COOKIE['email'] . '"
    };
    fcPreencheCampos(resposta);
</script>'
```

Dessa maneira, no seu `responseText`, você terá o código-fonte que deve ser fixado em uma `<div>` (por exemplo) para ser prontamente executado.

```
function ajax(){
    // ...

    // Ao receber a resposta, e após verificar se o status é 200, etc etc:
    document.getElementById("divExecuta").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

    // ...
}
```

Neste ponto, basta ter uma função, declarada em um script de `<head>`, por exemplo, que envie os dados para os campos assim que eles chegarem:

```
function fcPreencheCampos(dados){
    document.getElementById("inputNome").value = dados.nome;
    document.getElementById("inputEmail").value = dados.email;
}
```

O [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruipimentel/bm66yhfn/) não ajudará muito, neste caso; espero que a explicação seja suficiente para você entender! Abraços!

Comment: Yes, pré-formatar antes de enviar o resultado evita tanta dor de cabeça..!